# MS Access Named Query with parameters

Tags: ucanaccess

How do I call a named query with parameters?

I have the following query in MS Access called "getColor":

**SELECT * FROM WHERE Colors ID_COLOR = [PAR_ID]**

I have tried unsuccessfully with CallableStatement and PreparedStatement:

**connection.prepareCall("{call getColor(?)}");**

**connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM getColor ?");**

In advance thank you very much and sorry for my bad English, I am using a translator.

Answer (score 1):

yes they aren't implemented yet in UCanAccess. They will be available in the 3.0.3 as stored procedure so that you'll be able to use a CallableStatement. Translators are improving.